# cannot read tables from sqlite3 database attached in python

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I can connect to a database in sqlite3, attach another database and run an inner join to retrieve records from two tables, one in each database. But when I try to do the same with a python script running on the command line, I get no results - the error reads that the table (in the attached database) does not exist.

import sqlite3 as lite
db_acts = '/full/path/to/activities.db'
db_sign = '/full/path/to/sign_up.db'

def join_tables():

```
try:                     
    con = lite.connect(db_acts) 
    cursor = con.cursor()   
    cursor.execute("attach database 'db_sign' as 'sign_up'")    
    cursor.execute("select users.ID, users.Email, users.TextMsg from sign_up.users INNER JOIN db_acts.alerts on sign_up.users.ID = db_acts.alerts.UID") 
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print 'row', row            
    con.commit()
    con.close()               

except lite.Error, e:
    print 'some error'
    sys.exit(1)
```

The response on localhost is the same as on the HostGator remote host where I just ran a test (it's a new site without user inputs at the moment). I have no problem reading rows from tables in the original database connection - only the tables in the attached database are not read. The attachment works at least partially - a print statement to attach it in the except clause shows that the database is in use.

Comment: Put some print statements in that show where in the code you are.  If you make it past the 'attach database' command in the 'try' clause before failing to the 'except' and you again try to attach the database, you will see the error you are getting because you are trying to attach the database to the same name twice.

Comment: Thanks! A print statement works after attaching the database, but once the select statement is made (on a table from the attached database) nothing prints unless I copy the same statements to the 'except' clause - preceded by cursor.execute("detach database 'sign_up'") to avoid a 'database in use' error. The error reads "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: table_name" on any table from this database. How can a python sqlite3 db connection attach a database without its tables?

Comment: The problem is with the select statement. This prints the table structure for a table in a database attached with alias 'su': cursor.execute("select sql from su.sqlite_master where type='table' and name='users'"). But I haven't found how to get to the rows in that table.